# CSS issue in search bar form in smaller screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I encountered this strange CSS issue.When I use the page width more than some `700px`, it looks good.But the same thing, when I resize it less than `700px` (I am not sure of the correct size), it becomes crazily deformed. There's not much difference between the widths.

I have the following HTML and CSS that might be related:

```
<form class="navbar-form search-form" role="search" form="" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
  <div class="form-group ">
    <input type="text" name="s" id="search" size="27" class="form-control form-search search-text ac_input" placeholder="Type your search..." autocomplete="off">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn search-home  " name="subm">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search white"></span>
  </button>
</form>`
```

And this is the corresponding CSS that comes from BootStrap:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-form {
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}
.navbar-form {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1),0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1),0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}
```

Kindly help me with the issue to fix the search bar. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any place can we see this live? Or any [mcve]?

Comment: Ah... Okay, so is it Bootstrap?

Comment: Yes. And I didn't change it.

Comment: try to make your code more responsive, try adding media query for the resolutions where you are observing the issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the issue is with the `<input />` tag's parent. That's a `<div class="form-group">` and below `768px`, it breaks. I had the same issue. Kindly try this:

```
.navbar-form.search-form .form-group {
  float: left;
}
```

The `float: left` is removed in the smaller screens. Try this? This would default it for all the `.navbar-form.search-form` and I hope there's not any other forms using the same class.

Also, it is better if you add an `id` say, `#search-form` and then you can target it that way.

Comment: How did you know the form tag's parent was a div?  It's not shown in the code.

Comment: @pabrams Oops sorry. Not parent. LoL.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Ah okay, makes more sense now!  :)

Comment: @LGSon Stop mocking me now.

Comment: Not mocking, meant knowledgeable.

Comment: Thank you! It's looking great now! :)